# Connecting to cloudant NoSQL database from ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra, couchdb, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I have trouble connecting to my cloudant NoSQL database hosted on bluemix with couchrest_model library.

I have similar code written in ruby which works just fine from my computer (running locally, no rails or sinatra):

```
require 'couchrest'

url = "https://blah-blah@url with credentials.com"
database_name = "testdb"
db = CouchRest.database!(url+"/"+database_name)
db.save_doc('_id':"dog",:name => 'MonthyPython', :date => Date.today)
doc = db.get('dog')
```

The code above successfully writes data to my database. However, when I tried to do similar thing with the newest 'couchrest_model' gem, I got the

```
/Users/userpruser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:933:in `connect_nonblock': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

I have viewed several pages, but with no luck. So what is the correct way to make it work with just ruby (no rails) or/and ruby+sinatra? I find this recipe http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/models/couchdb but I have no idea how to sed the evniroment variables and how to put it together.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've added the ibm-bluemix tag for broader visibility. You can also try emailing to support@cloudant.com.

Comment: Thank you, I will try. I will also try to edit the comment and post some other code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like installing

```
gem install sinatra-config-file
```

and then requiring

```
require sinatra/config_file
```

solved my problem. Thanks to you all!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try explicitly setting the port to `443` and the protocol to `'https'`? See https://github.com/couchrest/couchrest_model#configuration

Comment: Yes, I have tried, but unfortunately, I have no idea how to load that configuration or if it is corretcly loaded